# Python requests application/x-www-form-urlencoded non json body

Tags: python, rest, curl, python-requests

I am trying to hit an API endpoint using python requests. I have been unable to successfully send the body of the request except when using cURL. Here is the cURL command that succeeds:

```
curl --location --request POST '<api endpoint url>' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
--data-urlencode 'obj={"login":"<email>","pword":"<password>"}'
```

Using python requests like this returns an error from the API because of the body of the request:

```
payload = 'obj={"login":"<email>","pword":"<password>"}'
headers = {
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
}
response = requests.post(url, headers=headers, data=payload)
print(response.text)
```

I also tried `requests.request("POST")` but got the same results.

Answer (score 2):

Your data is URL encoded as you can see in the `curl` Content-Type header, so you have to provide the data in an URL encoded format, not JSON.

Use the following instead. `requests` will set the Content-Type header to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` automatically. It will also take care of the [URL encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding).

```py
data = {"login": "<email>", "pword": "<password>"}
response = requests.post(url, data=data)
```